# Ember custom JSON

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Im having a hard time figuring out how i would tell Ember to serialize this json example

```
{
   "error":false,
   "data":{
      "total":1,
      "per_page":15,
      "current_page":1,
      "last_page":1,
      "from":1,
      "to":1,
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"11",
            "type":"1",
            "body":"a simple body",
            "owner":"14",
            "published":"1",
            "updated_at":"2013-12-10 14:30:31",
            "created_at":"2013-12-10 14:30:31"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I can't figure out how to tell Ember that the data which is loaded from /feedItems are inside data and then data,

I have tried multiple things but can't grasp it, so far i have this in my app.js:

```
App.FeedItem = DS.Model.extend({
    error: DS.attr('boolean'),
    data: DS.hasMany('FeedItemData')
});

App.FeedItemData = DS.Model.extend({
    data: DS.hasMany('FeedItemDataData')
});

App.FeedItemDataData = DS.Model.extend({
   body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.FeedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('FeedItem');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is incorrect. Models should represent the way your data ought to look, no the way that it is returned from the server. `FeedItemData` and `FeedItemDataData` are not logical entities in your application and therefore should not exist.

You need to create `FeedItemSerializer` (or `ApplicationSerializer` if all your data is formatted this way) that would look something like this:

```
 FeedItemSerializer = Ember.RESTSerializer.extend({
   normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
     if(!payload.error) {
       return payload.data.data;
     } else {
       // handle the error
     }
   }
 });
```

Or alternatively do something similar in `extractArray` [as documented here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray).